# category title after ajax load more goes beyond <a> </a>

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I added a piece of code that displays the current entry categories. With normal loading everything is fine, but by clicking on the load more, which uses AJAX, the category name goes beyond . What's the problem?

```
?>
<div class="kategoria-wpisy">
    <?php 
    $category = get_the_category(); 

    if (!empty($category)) {
        $category_id = get_cat_ID( $category[0]->cat_name );
        echo "<a href=". get_category_link( $category_id ) . ">" . $category[0]->cat_name . "</a>"; 
    }

    ?>
</div>
```

After load more must be the same like previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your ajax request, you're having an issue with your quotes around the href attribute. Try this:

```
<div class="kategoria-wpisy">
    <?php 
    $category = get_the_category(); 

    if (!empty($category)) {
        $category_id = get_cat_ID( $category[0]->cat_name );
        echo '<a href="'. get_category_link( $category_id ) . '">' . $category[0]->cat_name . '</a>'; 
    }

    ?>
</div>
```